# Checkbox returning two values

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently using javascript to generate HTML for checkboxes however when I go to post the form to my controller which accepts `FormCollection` as a parameter.

I then put these values into a dictionary and inspect the value within my dictionary.  While other checkboxes only return one value, my `autoDiscovery` checkbox returns two which are `'on'` and `'true'`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Here is the rendered HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="autoDiscovery">
            <input id="autoDiscovery" type="checkbox" checked="" data-val="false" name="autoDiscovery">
            <input type="hidden" name="autoDiscovery" value="true"> Auto Discovery
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript I am using to assign the checkboxes

```
function AssignCheckbox(variableName, jsonData, caption) {
var checked = jsonData == 1 ? 'checked' : '';
var value = jsonData == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';    
    return divFormGroupOpening + divOpeningInput +
            '<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="' + variableName + '">' + '<input id="' + variableName + '" type="checkbox" name="' + variableName + '"  data-val="false"' + checked + '>' +
            '<input type="hidden" value="' + value + '" name="' + variableName + '">' +
            ' ' +  caption +'</label></div></div>';
        }
```

Comment: Don't check value, check the `checked` attribute.

Comment: Your check box does not have a value attribute - it needs to be `value="True"` and the hidden input needs to be `value="False"`

Comment: Why you have 2 inputs with the same names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the html generated when you use the `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` method. It generates

```
<input type="checkbox" name="autoDiscovery" value="true" ..... />
<input type="hidden" name="autoDiscovery" value="false" />
```

You need to mimic that. Currently your checkbox element does not have a value attribute so if its checked in the view it will post back "on". And your hidden input value is `"true"` so that value posts as well.

Just as important, do not use FormCollection. Post back to a model, or add a parameter in the method - `bool autoDiscovery` so the `DefaultModelBinder` will correctly set the value to either `true` or `false` depending on the checked state of the checkbox

Comment: So should the hidden input type always be false then?

Comment: Yes it should be `"false"` and the checkbox value should be `"true"`. This is by design. An unchecked checkbox does not post anything so in the controller you get `false`. But a checked checkbox does post back, so the values sent are `autoDiscovery=true&autoDiscovery=false` But the `DefaultModelBinder` reads only the first value (`true`) and ignores the second value.

Comment: I changed my value for the input field to false, and now the checkbox is true.  However it is still posting two values true and false

Comment: You need to read my last comment. All form controls (that are not disabled) post back their values. The `DefaultModelBinder` will take care of binding the property correctly (in MVC you should never need to use `FormCollection`) - just include `bool autoDiscovery` a a parameter in your POST method and test it with both the checkbox checked and unchecked - it will be correctly bound. If you insist on using `FormCollection` then you need to parse the values yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `input`s with the same exact `name` property. Ofcourse you would expect two values

```
<input id="' + variableName + '" name="' + variableName + '"  '>'
<input type="hidden" name="' + variableName + '">'
```

Comment: The thing is, why do my other checkboxes not return two values? I am using the exact same code to generate my HTML the only difference is the others are false where as autoDiscovery is true.